# How to select 'mat-checkbox' in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have 4 check box and need to select the checkbox. The code is written in Angular and I am using selenium for automation.

please find the code.

I need to select "Main st & 19th St" check box.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CpPn.png)

Comment: your checkbox is not a native checkbox, so we don't know clicking on which element will trigger choosing the checkbox. In the screenshot, there are 4 elements: mat-checkbox, label, div, span,  you need to find out which element is the trigger and tell us. How to find out:  select a element per time in Chrome DevTool Element Tab, then switch to Console Tab and execute $0.click(), then observe the checkbox is choosen or not.

Comment: @Raa If you're using Chrome. **Right Click and Inspect element**, Now after the inspect, over the highlighted code, **Right Click -> Copy -> XPath**, this will give you the XPath value. Try using that. For Click either use `click()` or use `jsexecutor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try the following code.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='mat-checkbox-label'][text()='Main st & 19th St']")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mat-checkbox-1']/label")).click();
```

Comment: you can try click on any mat checkbox layout label or span element inside label. it should work.